# How do I pass bound data to a function in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to make a small multiples chart by following Mike Bostock's [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9490313).

This example uses `enter().append("svg")` to create a new SVG for each data point. In each SVG you would then create the chart.

I have data that is in a CSV file that looks like this:

```
count, radius  
15, 5  
10, 3
```

With this data I'd like to create two SVGs (one for each data point), with the first one containing 15 circles each with a radius of 5, and the second svg containg 10, each with a radius of 3. I have a function `drawCircles` that I wish to use to draw the circles based on my dataset, however I'm having trouble passing the data through to my function.

Here's my code:

```
d3.csv("nations.csv", function(data) {
var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

  drawCircles(function (d) {return +d.count;}, function (d) {return     +d.radius;})
```

I can't seem to pass `d.count` and `d.radius` through as arguments to my `drawCircles` function. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Your data looks to be in JSON format but your using `d3.csv()`?

Comment: Apologies (as I said very new) - my data is actually in a csv file with column headers count and radius. Was unsure how to describe my dataset. I've edited my question to hopefully clarify.

Comment: We need to see more code to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a **very** d3ish way of doing what you are after:

```
  d3.csv("some.csv", function(d){
      // coerce your data to numbers
      return {
        count: +d.count,
        radius: +d.radius
      } 
    },
    function(data){        
      // create your svg for each row of data
      var s = d3.selectAll("svg")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 600)
        .attr("height", 100);

      // use a sub-selection to create a circle for each count
      s.selectAll('circle')
        .data(function(d){
          // the bound data will simply be an array with repeating radius
          return d3.range(d.count).map(function(_){ return d.radius });
        })
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        // radius is the same for each circle
        .attr('r', function(d){
          return d;
        })
        // space the circles so they look good;
        .attr('cx', function(d,i,j){
          return ((d + 2) * 2) * i + 10;
        })
        .attr('cy', 50)
        .style('fill', 'steelblue');        
  });
```

---

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Pa6p3zygSKBDE6Y6yMS?p=preview).